# Inserting students into a list based on id number

Tags: java, for-loop, linked-list

So i'm working on a method and i'm a little confused the point is the insort a student into a list based on there id number so students with lower id numbers come first etc... I'm confused what to do inside my if statment once i check if it is larger.

the code i have now is

```
public boolean insort(StudentIF s) {
    StudentLLNode curr = head;

    if (s == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (head == null) {
        StudentLLNode student = new StudentLLNode(s);
        head = student;
        size++;
        //System.out.println("working");
        return true;
    } else {
        if (curr.getStd().compareTo(s) == 0) {
            //System.out.println("working");
            return false;
        }
        while (curr.getNext() != null) {
            if(s.compareTo(curr.getStd()) == 1){
                //confused here 
            }
            curr = curr.getNext();
        }
        //confused here
        StudentLLNode student1 = new StudentLLNode(s);
        curr.setNext(student1);
        size++;
        return true;
    }
}
```

my compare to method is

```
public int compareTo(StudentIF other) {
    if (other == null) {
        return 1;
    } // satisfies null student
    if (this.id > other.getId())
        return 1;
    else if (this.id < other.getId())
        return -1;
    else
        return 0; // if it's neither smaller nor larger, it must be equal
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = Collections.binarySearch(myStudentList, studentObject);
myStudentList.add(index < 0 ? -1 * (index + 1) : index, studentObject);
/* OR
if(index < 0)
    myStudentList.add(-1 * (index + 1), studentObject);
If you did not want to add duplicates
*/
```

Binary search returns the index of the studentObject, or `-(insertIndex) - 1` if the object is not in the list.